AWS MWAA Custom UI Alert Message

According to Apache Airflow's documentation, I can add a custom banner by creating airflow_local_settings.py file with the following code:
from airflow.www.utils import UIAlert

DASHBOARD_UIALERTS = [
    UIAlert("Welcome to Airflow"),
]

This will automatically be loaded and reflected in the UI, as shown above.
What's the equivalent for AWS' MWAA? I tried uploading airflow_local_settings.py to the DAG code bucket but the banner does not appear.

I ended up figuring this out. You do upload the airflow_local_settings.py to the dag folder but you also have to trigger an update to the environment either via the console or cli (aws mwaa update-environment).
